# Order numbers with Lua

Tags: lua

I'm trying to make something to find the median, mode, mean, and range of a set of data. Mean is easy to find using the programming; but median, mode, and range require the numbers to be in order (from least to greatest).

Also, I'm trying to assemble it so it returns the data I would need to make a box and whisker plot. (Not all, just the basic).

Right now I'm simply working on this:
Order the numbers into a table (that a function will return)

QWERTYUIOP[]\

Okay, here's the main question:
How would I do this?

This is what I'm running on:

```
function Order_Numbers(Data_Set, Greatest_Integer, Least_Integer)
local Ordered = {} --Give a place for the numbers to go
for i=Least_Integer, Greatest_Integer do --Start from the lowest value, continue to highest.
table.insert(Ordered, Data_Set[i])
end
return Ordered
end
```

But it doesn't work!
Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered using [`table.sort`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.5)? It even allows you to provide a function to do the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

If you can sort in place, use `table.sort(Data_Set)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
The Lua distribution includes sort.lua which has a simple implementation of quick sort; slightly simplified, the core is as follows:

function qsort(vec, low, high)
  if low < high then
    local middle = partition(vec, low, high)
    qsort(vec, low, middle-1)
    qsort(vec, middle+1, high)
  end
end
```

-> http://lua-users.org/wiki/LazySort

Comment: This would be super helpful, 
'> attempt to call global "partition" (a nil value)'